# intializing Bot using Github repository

Tags: github

Can someone help me with:

I understand how to clone repo, but I don't know what installing requirements mean?

And how do i run program on Mac?

thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends on which language you are using in the code you are cloning.

Comment: Hi, the steps depend on what language and technologies are used in the repo. What repo are you trying to run?

Comment: I figured it out...my question centered around the following link:https://github.com/txiuqw4/farmersworld-bot.   I had to load instructions in mac terminal and load files from there.  thanks for feedback